# YII framework: How to pull data from database

Tags: php, database, frameworks, yii

I'm using a script that's built on the YII framework. I just added an extra table to the database, and want to know how I can pull data from it.

Lets say my table is called "clients", and my column is "name", how can I pull the data to show it?
I asked the owners of the script, but all they told me was to "define a controller and model to make it work"

Although I'm not bad with php and have done this before with Wordpress and stuff... I'm totally new and dumb with YII framework.

So I'm hoping you guys can help me with a code?

Comment: You need to checkout the tutorials. For starting try using gii to make your models, as it makes your models automatically. I recommend you to start from the [blog tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/) and try to follow this tutorial first. Then go on with the The [Definitive Guide to Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/download/)

Comment: I get that this might seem frustrating, and no one is answering your question, but as Yii's blog tutorial and the Definitive guide both cover this very clearly, it's unlikely anyone is going to help you until you make an effort to go through those first.  If you have specific questions or things that are failing, then people will be more likely to help.

Comment: This is covered quite extensively in the Definitive guide, read through this; [Getting Started](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app), and if you're still struggling I'd highly recommend [this book](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1847199585?ie=UTF8&tag=gii20f-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=1789&creativeASIN=1847199585) as a fantastic tutorial into the basics of Yii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know how to create model, try to use [Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii). Just add module definition to config and go to your.local.domen/gii. But better read [the docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/).

Comment: Thanks for telling me about GII

Answer (score 1):

Create a model for Emlpoyee, retrive the employe in a controller with:

```
$employee=Emlpoyee::model()->findByPk();
```

For example. Pass it to the view:

```
$this->render('view', array('employee'=>$employee));
```

Now in the view you can display your fields:

```
<?php echo $employee->ename?>
```

above from [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/15935-pull-data-from-db-to-view/)

Comment: yeah, I actually saw that exact same post here: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/15935-pull-data-from-db-to-view/ However, it didn't give any info on how to create a "model" so that doesn't help me to much.